# Iptables forward traffic destined for an ip to another ip

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have Host A `192.168.1.1`, Host B `192.168.1.2`, Host C `192.168.1.3` and Host D `192.168.1.4`. Host D is the router for the network. When Host A tries to reach Host B via http, I want Host A to actually reach Host C. The problem is Host B doesn't actually exist, so `/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:80` didn't work and the connection times out. This configuration worked when Host B existed. Iptables can only be run on host D. Is there any way this setup can work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because Host D was never used as all the hosts *appears* to be in the same IP subnet and LAN.

You can add a host route on `192.168.1.1` for `192.168.1.2` **and** a host route on `192.168.1.3` for `192.168.1.1`, both with `192.168.1.4` as the gateway (`via`). (The latter route is for the "reverse NAT".)

If you want to do it generally, you should *avoid* using a non-`/32` prefix (e.g. `/24`) when configure IP on the hosts (other than `192.168.1.4`) but instead set `192.168.1.4` as the `peer`.